# java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key size

Tags: java, android, encryption, netbeans, bouncycastle

I am building a desktop app in netbeans in order to load the keys on the pinpad (device) . The same code runs on the android and works fine with 16 byte keys but on the desktop app it throws me error 16 bytes but it works fine with 24 byte keys, error is :

```
    java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key size
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCrypt.init(DESedeCrypt.java:69)

    at com.sun.crypto.provider.ElectronicCodeBook.init(ElectronicCodeBook.java:93)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:582)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:458)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineInit(DESedeCipher.java:166)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:797)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:859)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1229)

    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1166)
    at payokeygen.CryptoUtil.encrypt3DESECB(CryptoUtil.java:62)
    at payokeygen.UseDatecs.loadKeys(UseDatecs.java:135)
    at payokeygen.mainscreen.loadPPEKeysActionPerformed(mainscreen.java:435)
    at payokeygen.mainscreen.access$300(mainscreen.java:34)
    at payokeygen.mainscreen$4.actionPerformed(mainscreen.java:186)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at com.datecs.pinpad.Pinpad.cryptoExchangeECBKey(Pinpad.java:1362)
    at payokeygen.UseDatecs.loadKeys(UseDatecs.java:135)
    at payokeygen.mainscreen.loadPPEKeysActionPerformed(mainscreen.java:435)
    at payokeygen.mainscreen.access$300(mainscreen.java:34)
    at payokeygen.mainscreen$4.actionPerformed(mainscreen.java:186)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

code to load the keys on pinpad is :

```
 pinpad.cryptoExchangeECBKey(HMK_INDEX, KEK_PIN_INDEX, Pinpad.KEY_KEK_PIN, 0, CryptoUtil.encrypt3DESECB(HMK, KEK_PIN));
```

encrypt3DESECB function in "CryptoUtil" is :

```
public static byte[] encrypt3DESECB(byte[] keyBytes, byte[] dataBytes) {
    try {
        SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, newKey);
        System.out.println("function called");
        return cipher.doFinal(dataBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

16 bytes Key is : 1A C4 F2 34 79 CD 8F 23 0B C4 9D 2C 98 C8 91 EA

Using JDK 1.8.
please help, thanks in advance !

Comment: what is the pinblock and key byte size?..its look like u are using wrong key byte size

Comment: 1AC4F23479CD8F230BC49D2C98C891EA this is the key

Comment: Make the above 16 byte key to 24 byte...by adding the first 8 bytes of the key to the end of the key...may it help u

Comment: @Kat-hat I have to use 16 byte , I can't use 24 byte. on 24 byte it works fine.

Comment: Behind the scene 3Des is actually just 3 single DES operations, that each require a 8 byte key. This gives the need for 24 bytes of key material .. however some implementations supports 16 bytes keys where the first 8 bytes are "automatically repeated" behind the scene for the 3. key.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen thanks nice explanation ,but how can I make it to support 16 bytes, because I am receiving the keys from the web service and I can't change the keys manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind the scene **3Des** is actually just 3 single DES operations, that each require a 8 byte key. This gives the need for 24 bytes of key material .. however some implementations supports 16 bytes keys where the first 8 bytes are "automatically repeated" behind the scene .. others might not support this. Howevere you can do this yourself by repeating the first 8 bytes - something like this:

```
public static byte[] encrypt3DESECB(byte[] keyBytes, byte[] dataBytes) {
    try {
        if (keyBytes.length == 16) { // short key ? .. extend to 24 byte key 
            byte[] tmpKey = new byte[24];
            System.arraycopy(keyBytes, 0, tmpKey, 0, 16);
            System.arraycopy(keyBytes, 0, tmpKey, 16, 8);
            keyBytes = tmpKey;
        }

        SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
        ...
        ...
```